# How to use IIF function in FastReports?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe8, fastreport

I have a field that contains an integer value (1 or 0 only), if the field contains 0 I want to print 'Male' in my report; if it's 1, then print 'Female'.

This is what I have done so far and it doesn't work:

```
[IIF(<ReportPersonal."civilStatus"> = 0, 'Male', 'Female')]
```

That code always prints 'Male' though the value of the **civilStatus** field is '1'.

Here is the [Link to the report file](https://www.mediafire.com/?213nu8jm3l21dam)

Advanced thanks to our experts.

Comment: Attach your report template (fr3) here

Comment: @gpi, I added a link in the question.

Comment: I want to mark @ValMarinov 's comment as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In MemoView "ReportPersonalcivilStatus" has :

```
DisplayFormat.FormatStr="False,True" DisplayFormat.Kind="fkBoolean".
```

Try to set `Memo - > Format` to `Text(no formating)`.

Answer (score 1):

```
[IIF(<ReportPersonal."civilStatus"> = True, 'Male', 'Female')]
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code-only answers are great, sure ... but, why not explain why your code would fix the issues the poster is having. This will help folks in the future who may have the same issue but don't know why.